# Default Table Model vs Abstract Table Model java

Tags: java, model, default, abstract

I want to create a JTable with the data inside based on some data structure in my code.

I tried to use a DefaultTableModel to display the data into my JTable but to make it coherent with the data structure i did ovveride some methods. In particular the methods are:

removeRow

addRow

fireTableCellUpdated

I only need to override this methods since I do simple stuff on the table but when i make changes (add, remove, update) of a row in the JTable i also want to update the data structure.

So what I did, on all of these methods, was to first do my stuff  (for example, in the removeRow method, i delete the entry from my data structure, then i simply call  the super.removeRow method to let the DefaultTableModel delete the row from the table)

I'm wondering if that's the right way to do this stuff, i also know that one can implement an AbstractTableModel but I don't really see the benefits in my case (I should do the same things i did on the Default Table Model, right?)

Are there other options to like "link" data structure to JTable and viceversa?

Any help is appreciated, thank you